# paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Tags: server, nginx

I am using `ubuntu` 18.04. i tried to uninstall `nginx` and i removed `/etc/nginx` directory. Now i want to reinstall `nginx` in my server, But i am getting following error.

```
root@localhost:~# apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nginx is already the newest version (1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnginx-mod-http-geoip : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-mail : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-stream : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
 nginx : Depends: nginx-core (< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: nginx-core (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to solve this error, But can't found any solution. Please help me to solve this error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried `apt --fix-broken install` like the error says?

Comment: I tried that command, but still get same error